# Make bootstrap-select responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have search control where i add textBox, select and button.

```
    <div class="col-md-10"> 
<div class="row">
        <div id="Search_Widget_tr3" class="input-group col-md-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter title" id="homeSearchInput"/>
            <div class="input-group-btn clearfix">
                <select class="selectpicker" multiple title='Platforms' data-container="body" data-count-selected-text="Platforms" data-selected-text-format="count>0" data-style="btn btn-default" data-allOptionIsSelected="false">
                    <option value="All">All Platforms</option>
                    <option value="Mobile Phone;Tablet;Windows Phone;PlayStation Certified Device;Windows 8 App;PlayStation Mobile">Mobile App/Tablet</option>
                    <option value="Nintendo DS;Nintendo DSi;Nintendo 3DS">Nintendo DS/DSi/3DS</option>
                    <option value="PlayStation 3">PlayStation 3</option>
                    <option value="PlayStation 4">PlayStation 4</option>
                    <option value="PSP;PS Vita">PlayStation Vita/PSP</option>
                    <option value="Wii">Wii</option>
                    <option value="Wii U">Wii U</option>
                    <option value="Linux;Macintosh;PC DVD;PC DVD-ROM;Windows CE;Windows PC;Windows 8 App">Windows/Mac</option>
                    <option value="Xbox 360">Xbox 360</option>
                    <option value="Xbox One">Xbox One</option>
                    <option value="3DO;Atari Jaguar;Atari Lynx;Cable Box;CDI;Dreamcast;DVD;Game Boy;Game Boy Advance;Game Boy Color;Game Gear;Game Wave(Custom DVD gaming platform);Game Cube;Gizmondo;Hyperscan;iPod;N-Gage;Neo Geo Pocket Color;Nintendo;Nintendo 64;Nintendo Game Boy;NUON;Online;Other;Palm Pilot;PDA(Palm, Win CE, etc.);PlayStation&2FPS one;PlayStation 2;Plug-and-Play;Pocket Arcade;Pocket PC;Pokemon Mini;Sega 32x;Sega CD;Sega Dreamcast;Sega Genesis;Sega Pico;Sega Pocket Arcade;Sega Saturn;Super Nintendo;VG Pocket;Virtual Boy;Web Browser;Web Site;Web TV;Xbox;Zodiac;Firefox">Other Platforms</option>
                </select>
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle click-search" type="button" aria-expanded="false">
                    Search <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                </button>
            </div><!-- /btn-group -->
        </div><!-- /input-group --> 

        </div>  </div>
```

Problem: I can't make the `<select>` responsive; it's width is fixed.

When i want to wrap it in some container and set `col-md-5` to this wrapper then i lost rounded corners between input and select (I don't want to add some new styles only for make corners rounded)

Here [**live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/m2y83djy/)

Comment: why can't you just add the rounded corners back?

Answer (score 6):

simple solution: add class `form-control` to the select element

Answer (score 2):

I looked in the css to see what was "holding" the select box open and found that it was set to 220px width.

If you add this to your custom css it should work fine:

```
.bootstrap-select:not([class*=col-]):not([class*=form-control]):not(.input-group-btn) {
    width: auto;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m2y83djy/1/

Comment: i provided width in percentage because i have more then 10 select in a single page so they have same width at least.